# Is there any way to connect multiple Cloud memorystore instances through single Compute Engine's VM instance

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

I require distributed cache environment using cloud memorystore so I am trying to create two cloud memorystore instances and trying to connect with an VM instance

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Unable to connect the different memory stores from a single Vm instance at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to cloud memorystore only within the same region. So your distributed caches should reside in same region to be able to connect from the VM in the same region.
From the docs : https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/regions

"You can only connect to a Cloud Memorystore for Redis instance from resources in the same region as your instance. Resources in different zones within the same region can connect, however provisioning resources in the same zone improves network performance."